# How to initialize existing Angular 6 app after copying the files to another folder?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have copied all the files and folders of my angular 6 app(except *node_modules* folder) from another disk, now I am searching for the solution to initialize it as we do it in node project.

consider this (node.js example):

- we have a node project, after copying all files and folders except node_modules.
- we run `npm install` which downloads all dependencies referring to `package.json`
- than run `npm start`, this starts the node app perfectly.

I am trying same for **Angular app**, did `npm install`, followed by `ng serve` but getting the error as bellow:

> Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from
>   "E:\ang\dragAngTodo".

package.json

```
{
  "name": "drag-todo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.5",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.1",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your `package.json` as well.

Comment: Check your npm and node versions on other pc

Comment: got it, that was the change in angular version. old files were from **angular 6** and I was trying to `ng serve` it, whereas the `npm install` had installed the dependencies of **angular 7**. `ng update --all` did it all. even the package.json I added is the new one, previous one was modified after `ng update`